# Linux : what is the order of execution of *.desktop files in autostartup

Tags: linux, desktop, startup, application-start

Need to launch two application on system startup. 
A desktop file is created starting the fist one. Unfortunately could not find any way to launch the two application in single desktop file. If there is way please write in comments ?

As a workaround created the second desktop file for launching the second app. 
Now Need to know the order of invoking *.desktop files in autostartup. 
It that performed by alphabetical order ?

Regards,
Levon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always run script, which will then run your applications. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

app1
app2
```

or, if you don't want to keep separate script, adding line `Exec=app1;app2` to your .desktop file may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks "Exec=app1; sleep 0.25; app2" helped